# Can I get the robocopy log file to just display one line of the summary and date? instead of having multiple columns? thank you

Tags: powershell, file, logging, robocopy, short

So far I have this code to just show the summary of the robocopy. Can I just make this really short and 1 line? Like a line that shows the total size copied, the date, and if it was successful or something like that. Thanks

`/Z /e /xx /W:5 /NFL /NDL /NJH /nc /np /unilog+:$Logfile`

This is the output:

```
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         0         0         0         0
   Files :        10         1         9         0         0         0
   Bytes :   1.009 g  102.79 m  931.15 m         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:06   0:00:06                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            15897359 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             909.654 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Thursday, April 29, 2021 11:24:08 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a little Select-String, Trim, & Split.

```
Clear-Host
#Next line for testing only you can delete since you already have it defined!
$LogFile =  "G:\BEKDocs\Batch\BackupTasks\RoboCopyNAS.log"

$Log = Get-Content -Path "$LogFile"

$Bytes = $($Log | Select-String -Pattern "Bytes :" -SimpleMatch).Line.Trim(" ")
$DT    = $($Log | Select-String -Pattern "Ended :" -SimpleMatch).Line.Trim(" ")

$Parts = $Bytes.Split(" ")

$Bytes = $Parts[3] + $Parts[4]

"Bytes Copied: $Bytes on $($DT.Trim('Ended :'))"
```

Result:

```
Bytes Copied: 27.493g on Thursday, April 29, 2021 6:15:20 PM
```

HTH

Comment: Hi I want it to get that result onto a text file from robocopy so that when i get the email it will show the result you put. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think you have to use Add-Content

Comment: Also the bytes part of the single line didnt go through. "Bytes Copied:  on Friday, April 30, 2021 9:44:38 AM"

Comment: I don't know a way to get the line into the RoboForm Email as it will be processed before control returns to PowerShell to process the Log file. You could of course kill the RoboForm Email and send one from PowerShell after you've processed the Log file.

Comment: how would I send the one from Powershell? sorry Im new to this. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Use the Send-MailMessage cmdlet.

Comment: any idea why the the bytes isnt showing up? it give me this output: Bytes Copied:  on Friday, April 30, 2021 11:31:17 AM

Comment: Don't know why it isn't showing up, works fine for me. Are you sure it is copying something? BTW if you are using Outlook as you email server see this:https://tekcookie.com/send-email-from-outlook-using-powershell/2

Comment: yes it did copy things. it doesnt show up